# Margem dentro de tabela

Tags: html, css

Tenho um texto dentro de uma "tabela", porem basicamente queria colocar margem lateral, como um paragrafo.
Maggin, padding, entre outras formas não consegui.

Meu código HTML:

```
< div class="container texto" id="camps" >  
< ul >
< li >
< img class="minijogos" src="imagens/fifa.png" >
< p>< h2>FIFA</h2>
Modalidade: <i>Futebol</i></br>
Jogador por equipe: <i>01</i></br>
Tipo de Competição: <i>Melhor de 2 com saldo de gol</i></br>
Plataforma: <i>PS3, PS4 ou XBOX</i></br>
Descrição: <i>Sem muito a dizer, os campeonatos de FIFA tem a regras simples e seguimento da competição rígido, mantendo o tradicional mata com saldo de gol, o s jogadores e enfrentam entre si duas vezes onde chegaram ao resultado final.< /i></br>
< /p>
< /li>
```

CSS:
"

```
#camps{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}


#camps ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 90%;     /* Comprimento da grade */
    height: 500px;  /* Altura da grade */
    background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.5);
    margin: 10px 50px 0px 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid white;

}


    .container ul li{
        float: none;
        width: 30%;
        margin: 40px auto;
    }
}
```

"

Help plz *_*

Answer (score 1):

Deixa eu ver se entendi sua dúvida, você quer assim?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for isso, você adiciona no css o codigo abaixo:

```
.recuo { 
    text-indent:2em 
}
```

---

e dentro do `h2` de qualquer texto que desejar é só colocar **"class='text-info recuo"**

```css
camps{
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px auto;
padding: 30px 0px;
}

camps ul li{
list-style: none;
float: left;
width: 90%;     /* Comprimento da grade */
height: 500px;  /* Altura da grade */
background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.5);
margin: 10px 50px 0px 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid white;
}

.container ul li{
    float: none;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

.recuo { 
text-indent:2em 
}
```

```html
<div class="container texto" id="camps" >
<ul> <li > <img class="minijogos" src="imagens/fifa.png" > <p><h2 class='text-info recuo' >FIFA Modalidade: Futebol Jogador por equipe: 01 Tipo de Competição: Melhor de 2 com saldo de gol Plataforma: PS3, PS4 ou XBOX Descrição: Sem muito a dizer, os campeonatos de FIFA tem a regras simples e seguimento da competição rígido, mantendo o tradicional mata com saldo de gol, o s jogadores e enfrentam entre si duas vezes onde chegaram ao resultado final.</i> </p> </ul> </li>
<ul> <li > <img class="minijogos" src="imagens/fifa.png" > <p><h2 class='text-info recuo' >FIFA Modalidade: Futebol Jogador por equipe: 01 Tipo de Competição: Melhor de 2 com saldo de gol Plataforma: PS3, PS4 ou XBOX Descrição: Sem muito a dizer, os campeonatos de FIFA tem a regras simples e seguimento da competição rígido, mantendo o tradicional mata com saldo de gol, o s jogadores e enfrentam entre si duas vezes onde chegaram ao resultado final.</i> </p> </ul> </li>

</div>
```

Comment: Preferencialmente use o o **snippet** do editor de texto, assim os usuários que chegarem  questão (e a resposta) poderão observar o código sem a necessidade de ir a outro site.